# Varnish 4.0.1, Apache, Centos 7, Plesk 12, Wordpress with w3 total cache - Varnish not caching html

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, centos7, varnish-4

I set up varnish on my site the other day and I don't believe it is working correctly as the age shows as 0:

```
The url we checked: pbsgroups.deep-image.co.uk
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:   Wed, 24 Feb 2016 09:57:14 GMT
Server: Apache
Link:   <http://pbsgroups.deep-image.co.uk/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <http://pbsgroups.deep-image.co.uk/>; rel=shortlink
Expires:    Wed, 24 Feb 2016 10:57:15 GMT
Pragma: public
Cache-Control:  max-age=3600, public
X-Powered-By:   PleskLin
X-Pingback: http://pbsgroups.deep-image.co.uk/xmlrpc.php
Vary:   Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: iSLuxE=1; expires=Wed, 24-Feb-2016 12:57:14 GMT; Max-Age=10800
Last-Modified:  Wed, 24 Feb 2016 09:57:15 GMT
Etag:   33984224b175af821c75fc660dbd42a8
X-Mod-Pagespeed:    1.10.33.5-0
Content-Encoding:   gzip
Content-Length: 7851
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Varnish:  655877
Age:    0
Via:    1.1 varnish-v4
Connection: keep-alive
```

Static content works perectly:

```
The url we checked: pbsgroups.deep-image.co.uk/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.4.2
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date:   Wed, 24 Feb 2016 09:34:34 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 28526
Last-Modified:  Thu, 18 Feb 2016 11:04:30 GMT
ETag:   "b438-52c0954a5d637-gzip"
Vary:   Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Cache-Control:  max-age=31536000, public
Expires:    Thu, 23 Feb 2017 09:08:56 GMT
X-Powered-By:   W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1
Pragma: public
X-Original-Content-Length:  46136
Content-Encoding:   gzip
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type:   text/css
X-Varnish:  361406 820497
Age:    21
Via:    1.1 varnish-v4
Connection: keep-alive
```

This is what isvarnishworking.com has got to say on this:

```
Varnish appears to be responding at that url, but the Cache-Control header's "max-age" value is less than 1, which means that Varnish will never serve content from cache at this url.
```

Here is a copy of my .htaccess (made with w3 total cache):

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
# BEGIN W3TC CDN
<FilesMatch "\.    (asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|woff|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|WOFF|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:http://pbsgroups.deep-image.co.uk {REQUEST_URI},NE]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
  RewriteRule .* - [E=CANONICAL:https://pbsgroups.deep-image.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI},NE]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Link "<%{CANONICAL}e>; rel=\"canonical\""
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC CDN
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/x-component .htc
AddType application/x-javascript .js
AddType application/javascript .js2
AddType text/javascript .js3
AddType text/x-js .js4
AddType text/html .html .htm
AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
AddType text/plain .txt
AddType text/xsd .xsd
AddType text/xsl .xsl
AddType text/xml .xml
AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
AddType video/avi .avi
AddType image/bmp .bmp
AddType application/java .class
AddType video/divx .divx
AddType application/msword .doc .docx
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
AddType image/gif .gif
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
AddType image/x-icon .ico
AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
AddType application/json .json
AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype .otf
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType application/pdf .pdf
AddType image/png .png
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
AddType application/x-tar .tar
AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
AddType application/vnd.ms-opentype .ttf .ttc
AddType audio/wav .wav
AddType audio/wma .wma
AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
ExpiresByType text/x-js A31536000
ExpiresByType text/html A3600
ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType application/json A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A31536000
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # DEFLATE by extension
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|LESS|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
FileETag MTime Size
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header unset Set-Cookie
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
FileETag MTime Size
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|woff|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|WOFF|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
FileETag MTime Size
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Pragma "public"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
     Header unset Set-Cookie
     Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The only thing that I could see different between the static files and html was that the html pages were sending cookies out, so I tried amending my default.vcl to unset cookies as follows:

```
sub vcl_recv {
if ( !( req.url ~ ^/admin/) ) {
unset req.http.Cookie;
}
}
```

I'm completely baffled by this now, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to the first part of your question:

```
Set-Cookie: iSLuxE=1; expires=Wed, 24-Feb-2016 12:57:14 GMT; Max-Age=10800
```

the origin is sending back cookies, which Varnish isn't going to cache.

So you'll want to do something like, assuming the cookies aren't actually relevant:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}
```

However, if both the request and response cookies are unnecessary, it seems like you could just remove them from the application. If the cookies are static and cacheable (and perhaps being used for a different subdomain), you could temporarily "move" them and restore them at response time:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.X-Set-Cookie = beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.X-Set-Cookie;
    unset resp.http.X-Set-Cookie;
}
```

This should allow Varnish to do it's normal cache processing without losing the cookies.